# How to use jQuery object for a select box

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am in need to have a value selected in a drop down and show that at a place.
The select box is formed using a variable,So what I did is

```
jQuery('<select>'+projAddHocs+'</select>')
    .find('[value='+val[59]+']')
    .attr('selected','selected')
    .prop('outerHTML');
```

or

```
jQuery('<select>'+projAddHocs+'</select>').val(val[59]).prop('outerHTML');
```

val[59] has the value which I need to be selected in the drop down before displaying.

It is easy when select exist in the DOM,but I am unable to do it using jQuery wrapper.

Any help/directions please?

Regards.

Comment: I am not sure as your question is not clear. But you can try `jQuery('<select>'+projAddHocs+'</select>').val(val[59]).end().prop('outerHTML');`

Comment: Your question isn't very clear. Can you set up a sample at jsfiddle.net or share the markup that this is supposed to work with?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are selecting `outerHTML` of your selected `<option>` because you got there through `find()`.

Go back to your `select` using `parent()`:

```
jQuery('<select>'+projAddHocs+'</select>')
    .find('[value='+val[59]+']')
    .attr('selected','selected')
    .parent()
    .prop('outerHTML');
```

**[See fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kLumz/)**

or, better:

```
var select = jQuery('<select>'+projAddHocs+'</select>');
select.find('[value='+val[59]+']').attr('selected','selected');

$('#wrapper').html(select.prop('outerHTML'));
```

**[See fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kLumz/1/)**

Comment: Can it be done by something like this jQuery('<select>'+projAddHocs+'</select>').val(val[59]).prop('outerHTML');

Comment: no, `val()` will only work after you add the element to HTML. like: http://jsfiddle.net/kLumz/2/

Answer (score 0):

Try this to retrieve the value of the select:

```
$("#mySelect").val(); // this returns the selected value of the drop down
// (assuming your select tag has id attribute with value 'mySelect')
```

If you want to set its value you can try this one:

```
$("#mySelect").val('myValue'); // this sets the value to 'myValue'
// If there is an '<option>' whose value is 'myValue', 
// then this option will be selected
```